# Разбор слово->сокращение, сокращение->слово в PyMorphy2 (JMorphy2)

Tags: python, pymorphy2

Можно ли управлять выдачей лем/лексем со связью Full-Contracted в библиотеке PyMorphy2 (JMorphy2) на основе словаря OpenCorpora?
Ибо имея на входе скажем слово "век" при переборе всех лексем мы получим и букву "в", что является предлогом и соответственно при поиске по слову "век" мы найдем все тексты где есть предлог "в", что совсем не то что ожидается.
Обратное так же верно.
Можно ли как-то этим управлять? Ограничивать выдачу лексем при обработке сокращений? 
И если да, то как? На уровне кода и/или словаря?
В исходнике словаря есть для этого специальный тип связи Full-Contracted. Но переходит ли он в откомпилированную DAWG версию?

Comment: Сокращение - это вообще в общем случае необратимая операция (как хэширование), так что всегда однозначного результата вы не получите. Если сокращение заканчивается на точку, то для "в" можно искать именно "в" с точкой, и при разборе отбирать именно разборы как сокращение.

Comment: Вообще, опишите подробнее свою задачу. Потому что именно для сокращения "в." для "век" все решается элементарно. В общем случае для разных сокращений решается сложно (если вообще решается).

Comment: Ситуация такая, что когда-то с год назад были взяты проекты pymorphy и jmorphy для питона и явы соответственно, с теми версиями словарей что были на тот момент. Все бы ничего, но тут стали замечать что не устраивает разбор некоторых слов по леммам. Скажем подавай на вход слово `"век"` мы получаем `"в"` и наоборот. Есть желание как-то с этим побороться ибо выдача используется потом для поиска и индексации в elastic, соответственно мы не хотим по запросу слова `"век"` найти все тексты с предлогом `"в"` и наоборот.

Comment: Была мысль убрать эти связи (не все , а только вот такие запутывающие, скажем, `"килограмм" -"кг"` никого не запутает) из исходного словаря и перекомпилировать его. Благо связи данные помечены в исходном словаре как FULL-CONTRACTED. Но во первых это не очень гибко, а во вторых с перекомпиляцией свежих словарей возникли сложности ( а исходника той давности нет). На что я хочу завести отдельную тему.

Comment: Можно фильтровать выдачу парсера, чтобы он не выдавал сокращения. Могу написать пример, но ближе к вечеру.

Comment: Да, про фильтрацию тоже была мысль. Точнее варианты были такие 1) Вмешаться в работу py/j-morphy и фильтровать выдачу внутри него 2) сделать дополнительный фильтр для ElasticSearch с какой-то своей матрицей переходов (ибо одно и тоже сокращение может быть от многих слов и где-то нужный эти связи, а где-то нет, где-то только в одну сторону, плюс при поиске и индексации может отличаться тоже поведение) и передавать его в качестве еще одного фильтра. Второй вариант для меня пока выглядит довольно сложным в плане реализации, но зато идейно наверно наиболее правильный.

Comment: За любые примеры кода, советы по реализации буду признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Примеры на слове "век". Парсим:

```
>>> import pymorphy2

>>> morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

>>> p = morph.parse('век')

>>> p

[Parse(word='век', tag=OpencorporaTag('ADVB'), normal_form='век', score=0.4, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'век', 3, 0),)),
 Parse(word='век', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,neut plur,gent'), normal_form='веко', score=0.2, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'век', 556, 7),)),
 Parse(word='век', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,nomn'), normal_form='век', score=0.2, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'век', 666, 0),)),
 Parse(word='век', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,accs'), normal_form='век', score=0.2, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'век', 666, 3),))]
```

Интересующие нас разборы - 3 и 4. Берем 3, получаем лексему (все варианты склонения/словоизменения):

```
>>> p[2].lexeme

[Parse(word='век', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,nomn'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'век', 666, 0),)),
 Parse(word='века', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,gent'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'века', 666, 1),)),
 Parse(word='веку', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,datv'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веку', 666, 2),)),
 Parse(word='век', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,accs'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'век', 666, 3),)),
 Parse(word='веком', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,ablt'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веком', 666, 4),)),
 Parse(word='веке', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,loct'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веке', 666, 5),)),
 Parse(word='веку', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,loc2'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веку', 666, 6),)),
 Parse(word='века', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,nomn'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'века', 666, 7),)),
 Parse(word='веков', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,gent'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веков', 666, 8),)),
 Parse(word='векам', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,datv'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'векам', 666, 9),)),
 Parse(word='века', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,accs'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'века', 666, 10),)),
 Parse(word='веками', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,ablt'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веками', 666, 11),)),
 Parse(word='веках', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,loct'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веках', 666, 12),)),
 Parse(word='веку', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,gen2'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веку', 666, 13),)),
 Parse(word='вв', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,nomn,Abbr'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'вв', 666, 14),)),
 Parse(word='вв', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,gent,Abbr'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'вв', 666, 15),)),
 Parse(word='вв', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,datv,Abbr'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'вв', 666, 16),)),
 Parse(word='вв', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,accs,Abbr'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'вв', 666, 17),)),
 Parse(word='вв', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,ablt,Abbr'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'вв', 666, 18),)),
 Parse(word='вв', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,loct,Abbr'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'вв', 666, 19),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,nomn'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 20),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,gent'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 21),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,datv'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 22),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,accs'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 23),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,ablt'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 24),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,loct'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 25),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,nomn'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 26),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,gent'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 27),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,datv'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 28),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,accs'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 29),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,ablt'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 30),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,loct'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 31),))]
```

Видим кучу вариантов с сокращениями, которые нам в принципе не нужны. Берем в руки генератор, и тупо фильтруем по тегу `Abbr` (abbrevation - сокращение):

```
>>> [item for item in p[2].lexeme if 'Abbr' not in item.tag]

[Parse(word='век', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,nomn'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'век', 666, 0),)),
 Parse(word='века', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,gent'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'века', 666, 1),)),
 Parse(word='веку', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,datv'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веку', 666, 2),)),
 Parse(word='век', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,accs'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'век', 666, 3),)),
 Parse(word='веком', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,ablt'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веком', 666, 4),)),
 Parse(word='веке', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,loct'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веке', 666, 5),)),
 Parse(word='веку', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,loc2'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веку', 666, 6),)),
 Parse(word='века', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,nomn'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'века', 666, 7),)),
 Parse(word='веков', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,gent'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веков', 666, 8),)),
 Parse(word='векам', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,datv'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'векам', 666, 9),)),
 Parse(word='века', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,accs'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'века', 666, 10),)),
 Parse(word='веками', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,ablt'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веками', 666, 11),)),
 Parse(word='веках', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc plur,loct'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веках', 666, 12),)),
 Parse(word='веку', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,gen2'), normal_form='век', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'веку', 666, 13),))]
```

Всего 14 строк (8 падежей в единственном числе + 6 падежей во множественном). 8 - потому что 2 местных (предложных) падежа (о ве́ке, на веку́) и 2 родительных (века, веку(?)).

Идем от обратного, пробуем "правильно" (без учета сокращений) разобрать слово "в":

```
>>> p = morph.parse('в')

>>> p

[Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('PREP'), normal_form='в', score=0.999764, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 375, 0),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,nomn'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 20),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,gent'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 21),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,datv'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 22),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,accs'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 23),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,ablt'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 24),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr sing,loct'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 25),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,nomn'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 26),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,gent'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 27),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,datv'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 28),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,accs'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 29),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,ablt'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 30),)),
 Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc,Fixd,Abbr plur,loct'), normal_form='век', score=1.9e-05, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 666, 31),))]
```

Снова берем генератор, фильтруем:

```
>>> [item for item in morph.parse('в') if 'Abbr' not in item.tag]

[Parse(word='в', tag=OpencorporaTag('PREP'), normal_form='в', score=0.999764, methods_stack=((<DictionaryAnalyzer>, 'в', 375, 0),))]
```

Сокращения ушли, остался только вариант разбора как предлога.

Справочная информация: [Руководство пользователя библиотеки Pymorphy2](http://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/guide.html)

Comment: Для этого надо доработать компилятор. Я создал заявку на проекте для этого https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2/issues/109